# How to use aynsc/await in javascript for returning objects from asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I cannot for the life of me figure out why async/await behaves the way it does.

Consider this example.

I want a function that does some db initialization, and returns me the database object when it is done.

```
var globalDb = null;

const IDB_DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
const IDB_STORE_NAME = "mystore";
const IDB_VERSION = 1.0;

async function initDb() {
    var idbOpenDbRequest = window.indexedDB.open(IDB_DATABASE_NAME, IDB_VERSION);

    idbOpenDbRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
            return event.target.result;
    };
}

(async () => {
    globalDb = await initDb();
    console.log("I should happen second")
    console.log(globalDb);
})();
```

### Expected

1. console.log("I should happen first")
2. console.log("I should happen second")
3. console.log(globalDb); //dumps the object to console

### Actual

1. console.log("I should happen second")
2. console.log(globalDb); //undefined
3. console.log("I should happen first")

I realize I am fundamentally misunderstanding something here. Please enlighten me why await does not work as I would expect. :)

### JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p2jqyrou/2/

Ps. Forget that this is about indexedDb and that this example is extremely simplified - I don't think it matters for the topic of this question.

Comment: There is indeed some confusion about just how async/await works here. I'll try and provide and answer but in the mean time maybe [this](https://www.asyncdrink.com/blog/async-await-basics) will help?

Comment: you are awaiting `initDb()`, but you can't await `setTimeout` as it doesn't returns a promise, hence console logs in unexpected (actually it's expected) order and function return undefined as it hasn't returned anything.

Comment: @TheReason he is returning stuff from `setTimeout` callback and expecting it to be the return for `initDb()`. @Kjensen it doesn't works like that.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I removed the setTimeout now, it was just illustrating a point about timing, which was stupid of me, as it adds complexity (and actually screwed my example up in this case). The fundamental question/problem is still the same: Why is nothing returned form the function - and why is the order of the console.log different than my expectation?

Comment: @Kjensen in order to get something from function you should return it first. Do you return anything from `initDb`?

Comment: @TheReason You mean like "return event.target.result;"?

Comment: `globalDb = await initDb()` awaits the return value of `initDb` function. The `initDB` function has no return statement of its own, therefore it returns undefined.

Comment: Still you are returning from callback of `onsuccess` but nothing is returned from `initDb()`. I can't explain any more why your expected order of `console.logs` is incorrect. Please read some documentation and stuff about timeout, promise, etc in js.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Mathyn understood perfectly my intention and provided and excellent answer. But thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is with your `initDb` function. I'll rewrite it for you and then explain why this version does work:

```
function initDb() {
    var idbOpenDbRequest = window.indexedDB.open(IDB_DATABASE_NAME, IDB_VERSION);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        idbOpenDbRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("I should happen first");
                resolve(event.target.result);
            }, 2000);
        };
    })
}
```

What I've done is wrap the `onsuccess` callback in a Promise. The async/await pattern in Javascript is fundamentally based around Promises. Either you return a Promise yourself or it wraps the result in a Promise (and immediately resolves it).

Because you did not return a Promise yourself it tried to wrap the return value (which was undefined) in a Promise. It then immediately resolved causing the async function to return.

With this updated code `initDb` is called which then returns a Promise which is only resolved after the connection has been made and after the timeout triggered.

Comment: )), actually i was writing same thing, but you was faster :O)

Comment: remove `async`, as it missleads

Comment: Exactly! You shouldn't be using `async` without await, pretty sure this code won't even compile, or i'm missing something? (Probably i'm talking about await keyword...)

Comment: Hang on, let me try. I believe it should compile.

Comment: Good point on not using the await keyword in the function. I'll remove the `async` keyword.

Comment: Works just fine here as well, great answer!

Comment: @Kjensen you can indeed use the function both with and without `async`. I have chosen to remove it in the answer because I do not use the `await` keyword in the function itself.

Comment: @Mathyn And thanks for providing the explanation as well. It makes sense. :)